# Multiple React components relying on the same UseEffect() condition

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

Let's say I have two React components, A and B.  Both components have a useEffect that 'listens' to the same condition (condition1, which could be a global variable, as in some React Context).  When the context variable changes, which component's useEffect() is executed first?

Component A {
React.useEffect(() => {
        *do something*
    }, [condition1]);
}

Component B {
React.useEffect(() => {
        *do something else*
    }, [condition1]);
}

Comment: It would depend on the hierarchy of said components. Are they siblings or parent/child?

Comment: Hi, that makes sense.  The components are siblings, but Component A is rendered before Component B, and I notice that Component A's useEffect is triggered first.  Pseudo code:                                                                                         
                                                                                                                     return (
<div>
 <ComponentA>
 <ComponentB>
</div>
)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you, Chris.  You've answered this question.  When multiple components reference the same condition in a conditional useEffect(), whichever component is higher-up in the hierarchy will have its useEffect executed first.